# Как изменить переменную цикла в цикле for? Так что бы значения не повторялись

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for

Попытаюсь объяснить.
Как сделать так: например в Blog 1 идут id 1-3, в Blog 2 идут 4-6, в Blog 3 идёт 7,8?

```
posts = []
for i in range(1, 9):
    posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=1))
    posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=2))
    posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

примерно так:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    posts.append(i)
    posts.append(i + 3)
    posts.append(i + 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

вариант 1:

```
posts = []

for i in range(1, 4):
    posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=1))

for i in range(4, 7):
    posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=2))

for i in range(7, 9):
    posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=3))
```

вариант 2:

```
posts = []
for i in range(1, 9):
    if 1 <= i <= 3:
        posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=1))

    if 4 <= i <= 6:
        posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=2))

    if 7 <= i <= 8:
        posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
posts = []
for i in range(1, 9):
    posts.append(Post(post_id=i, Blog=(i-1)//3+1))
```